# How to set chrome options for aerokube moon on C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenoid, aerokube-moon

I am trying to run my selenium tests on aerokube moon

I can see moon ui at http://moon.aerokube.local/ with default configuration.

taking reference from java example project on their github I have setup moon capabilities as

```
Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> moonoption = new Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>();
            moonoption.Add("enableVideo", true);
            moonoption.Add("enableVNC", true);
            moonoption.Add("videoName", testName + ".mp4");
ChromeOptions copt = new ChromeOptions();
copt.AddAdditionalCapability("moon:options", moonoption);
```

but when I run the tests I get the error

[image]

How to add the moon capabilities for moon in C#

also no tag for moon is available so add so adding selenoid
**edit:**
I am using Selenium 3.

Comment: Added respective tag for Moon.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `moon:options` on the top level of capabilities object. Your code is adding the same key under `goog:chromeOptions` which is wrong.

Comment: can you please give the example how am I supposed to do this.

Comment: adding the key under chrome as u put works in selenium 4 . if I upgrade to selenium 4 and use chromeOptions.AddAdditionalOption("moon:options" moon) works

Comment: If I remember correctly ChromeOptions in Selenium 3 should be added under DesiredCapabilities.

Comment: No , ChromeOptions are converted to capabilities by calling chromeOption.ToCapability()
also DesiredCapabilities class is deprecated in Selenium3.
In Selenium4 moon is being added under chromeoptions too